# NSDate is off by one day?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm attempting to compare two dates together to decide how much time is between them. For some reason I keep getting it all by one day off. I'm not too sure what is causing it, but I believe it to be the time zones? Do I have to specifically set that?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];

newAssignment.dueDate = [formatter stringFromDate:self.dueDatePicker.date];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

//Difference between dates test
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:today toDate:self.dueDatePicker.date options:0];
newAssignment.daysUntilAssignmentDueInt = [comps day];

//Test to compare dates
NSLog(@"\n\ntoday's date: %@\ndate picked: %@\ndue in: %d\n", today, self.dueDatePicker.date, newAssignment.daysUntilAssignmentDueInt);
```

My NSLog outputs:

```
today's date: 2013-11-03 03:17:26 +0000
date picked: 2013-11-05 04:17:12 +0000
due in: 1
```

I've gone so much as to think today's Daylight Savings change would be changing all of this. But I'm just not sure anymore.

EDIT: I've read a few other posts here on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to see anyone who is experiencing what I am.

Comment: What time zone are you in/using?

Comment: `newAssignment.dueDate` should be a NSDate, not a NSString

Comment: Apparently there's a DST bug in iOS 7, which may have something to do with this, although I was able to reproduce it on Mountain Lion. Note that the full set of date components for the difference is 1 day, 23 hours, 59 minutes, and 46 seconds. It's as if the time zones are being factored into the arithmetic. The dates would be, e.g. (west coast of N. America) 2013-11-02 08:17:26 -0700 and 2013-11-04 08:17:12 -0800 in their "own" time zones, crossing the DST transition line. If the arithmetic somehow included those zones, the difference is as given. DST/summer time weirds calendars.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I think you're right. I especially noticed the day right after our recent DST change. The NSLog began outputting slightly different information.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, you were right. Changing it to an NSDate helped sort the code out correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I've used nearly identical code to what you posted and I get correct results.

My code is a class method that relies on a global gregorian calendar that is set up in advance by the class's +initialize method, but the idea is the same. Here's my method:

```
+ (NSInteger) daysBetweenStartDate: (NSDate*) startDate andEndDate: (NSDate*) endDate;
{
    NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [gregorian components: NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0]; 
    return dateComponents.day;
}
```